# Bizarre problem with React component which renders wrong HTML code

Tags: reactjs

One of my React components is misbehaving. In a sense that it renders the wrong HTML code
when state is set to `true`:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import Brand from "./Brand";
import Navbar from "./Navbar";
import axios from "axios";

const EmailConfirmed = ({ match }) => {
  const { resp } = match.params;
  const [isEmailConfirmed, setEmailConfirmed] = useState(true);
  const [isAlreadyConfirmed, setAlreadyConfirmed] = useState(false);
  const [triggerRedirect, setTrigger] = useState(false);
  const [isInvalid, setIsInvalid] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (resp === "true") {
      setEmailConfirmed(true);
    } else if (resp === "failed") {
      setIsInvalid(true);
    } else if (resp === "already_confirmed") {
      setAlreadyConfirmed(true);
    } else {
      setTrigger(true);
    }
  }, [resp]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setAlreadyConfirmed(false);
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      setTrigger(true);
    }, 7000);
  }, [isAlreadyConfirmed]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsInvalid(false);
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      setTrigger(true);
    }, 7000);
  }, [isInvalid]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTrigger(false);
    setEmailConfirmed(false);
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      setTrigger(true);
    }, 7000);
  }, [triggerRedirect]);

  return (
    <>
      <Brand />
      <Navbar />
      <br />
      <br />
      <div className="container">
        {triggerRedirect && <Redirect to="/login" />}
        {isEmailConfirmed && (
          <div className="notification is-success">
            Your email is now confirmed. Thank you. You will be taken to login
            page in few moments ....
          </div>
        )}
        {isInvalid && (
          <div className="notification is-warning">
            This verification appears to be invalid. Sorry. You will be taken to
            login page in few moment ...
          </div>
        )}
        {isAlreadyConfirmed && (
          <div className="notification is-info">
            Your email has been already confirmed before. No need to do it
            again. You will be taken to login page in few moments ....
          </div>
        )}
        {!isEmailConfirmed && (
          <div className="notification is-warning">
            Sorry, we couldn't confirm your email address. If problem persists
            please get in touch with me on ....
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default EmailConfirmed;
```

Please note that the default value of `isEmailConfirmed` is set to `true` at the moment hence

```
 {isEmailConfirmed && (
      <div className="notification is-success">
        Your email is now confirmed. Thank you. You will be taken to login
        page in few moments ....
      </div>
  )}
```

should be rendered. This block gets rendered instead:

```
{!isEmailConfirmed && (
      <div className="notification is-warning">
      Sorry, we couldn't confirm your email address. If problem persists
      please get in touch with me on ....
     </div>
)}
```

the value of `resp` is `true` too but it's not put in effect.

Any advice ?

Comment: `resp === true` ? And this code  `setTimeout(() => {<Redirect to="/login" />}, 7000);` not doing a thing

Comment: Yes. `resp` is `true`

Comment: @DennisVash Yeah that block of code I haven't taken off yet. I'm handling it in `return`.

Comment: @DennisVash Ohh I see. The thing is resp is "true" as a string. Is there a way to convert it into boolean ?

Comment: Just make a reproducible example in codesandbox [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Even it is a string, the if statement should evaluate it as true and go ahead and set value of the state variable to true. It's not doing it though.

Comment: You have other `useEffect` where `setEmailConfirmed(false);`

Comment: @DennisVash  Dammit I thought that is ran **after** the redirect is triggered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have another `useEffect` with contrast logic that always results in `isEmailConfirmed === false`.

Even if `isEmailConfirmed === true`, you will run this `useEffect` twice, and set it to `false`. Not sure what the logic behind it.

```
useEffect(() => {
    setTrigger(false);
    setEmailConfirmed(false);
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      setTrigger(true);
    }, 7000);
  }, [triggerRedirect]);
```

Comment: You're right. The thought behind it is that I thought it will be executed **after** the redirect gets triggered. My bad. It's working now.